# How to format a Decimal column in DB2?

Tags: db2

`Select totalvalue from user`

This DB2 query is giving output like, 
00000000000000000000072834.37000,
00000000000000000000147532.26000,
00000000000000000000145485.89000

I'd like to Display it as below,
72834.37,
147532.26,
145485.89

Is that possible in DB2? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: have you tried truncate() or float, decimal would be too small

Comment: I used TRIM function but it's not removing the extra 0's

Comment: try the truncate one then see what the output is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VARCHAR_FORMAT function should work in this case. Try out the below query:

```
SELECT 
VARCHAR_FORMAT(TOTALVALUE, 'S99999999999999999999999999.999999') 
FROM USER;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Strip(CHAR(DIGITS(00000000000000000000072834.37000)),L,'0')
```

it should give you `72834.37000`

Answer (score 0):

Your `DECIMAL` type is being returned as a `CHAR`.  If you're not doing it, then check your CLI settings for [`MapDecimalFloatDescribe`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0021614.html).