# How to return value with two decimal places

Tags: sql, db2

I am having trouble returning the result of a calculation with two decimal places, my query runs fine in my client but my presentation software seems to have a problem with CAST, is there another way/function I could use to accomplish this?

```
CASE
   WHEN HHICWCD = 'Y' THEN CAST((HHIEXCW * HHIPRCN) AS NUMERIC(5,2))
   WHEN HHICWCD = 'N' THEN CAST((HHIQYSA * HHIPRCN) AS NUMERIC(5,2))
   ELSE 0.00
   END AS "Extended Price",
```

Comment: Please share more info about "my presentation software seems to have a problem with CAST" Does it return wrong values? or an error, and if so which error ?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652994/how-to-format-a-decimal-column-in-db2

Comment: I am using AutoSQL to distribute the results of the query, the error I get is "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique or foreign-key constraints."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed DECIMAL(5,2) to DECIMAL(7,2) and it now works, thank you all for your help, learning every day!

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(CASE HHICWCD
   WHEN 'Y' THEN HHIEXCW * HHIPRCN
   WHEN 'N' THEN HHIQYSA * HHIPRCN
   ELSE 0
END AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS "Extended Price",
```

Comment: I am getting a "Failed to enable constraints" error that goes away if I comment out this section of code. Is there any way to accomplish this in another way?